# Unscale coefficient of scaled continuous variable in negative binomial regression

Tags: r, regression, coefficients

I'm fitting a negative binomial regression. I scaled all continuous predictors prior to fitting the model. I need to transform the coefficients of scaled predictors to be able to interpret them on their original scale. Example:

```
# example dataset
set.seed(1)
dep <- dnbinom(seq(1:150), size = 150, prob = 0.75)
ind.1 <- ifelse(sign(rnorm(150))==-1,0,1)
ind.2 <- rnorm(150, 10, 1.7)
df <- data.frame(dep, ind.1, ind.2)

# scale continuous independent variable
df$ind.2 <- scale(df$ind.2) 

# fit model
m1 <- MASS::glm.nb(dep ~ ind.1 + ind.2, data = df)
summz <- summary(m1)
```

To get the result for `ind.1` I take the [exponential of the coefficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/478385/31791):

```
# result for ind.1
exp(summz$coefficients["ind.1","Estimate"])
> [1] 1.276929
```

Which shows that for every 1 unit increase in `ind.1` you'd expect a 1.276929 increase in `dep`. But what about for `ind.2`? I gather that as the predictor is scaled the coefficient can be interpreted as the effect an increase of 1 *standard deviation* of `ind.2` has on `dep`. How to transform this back to original units? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14512787/1640528) says to multiply the coefficient by the sd of the predictor, but how to do this in the case of a logit link? `exp(summz$coefficients["ind.2","Estimate"] * sc)` doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Just a hint: define your `df` by using `df <- data.frame(dep, ind.1, ind.2)` instead of that `as.data.frame`-`cbind` construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up data:

```r
set.seed(1)
dep <- dnbinom(seq(1:150), size = 150, prob = 0.75)
ind.1 <- ifelse(sign(rnorm(150))==-1,0,1)
ind.2 <- rnorm(150, 10, 1.7)
df <- data.frame(dep, ind.1, ind.2)
sc <- sd(df$ind.2)
```

Fit unscaled and scaled models:

```r
m_unsc <- MASS::glm.nb(dep ~ ind.1 + ind.2, data = df)
m_sc <- update(m_unsc, data = transform(df, ind.2 = drop(scale(df$ind.2))))
```

Compare coefficients:

```r
 cbind(coef(m_unsc), coef(m_sc))
                   [,1]        [,2]
(Intercept) -5.50449624 -5.13543854
ind.1        0.24445805  0.24445805
ind.2        0.03662308  0.06366992
```

Check equivalence (we *divide* the scaled coefficient by the scaling factor (`sc`=`sd(ind.2)`) to get back the unscaled coefficient):

```r
all.equal(coef(m_sc)["ind.2"]/sc, coef(m_unsc)["ind.2"])
```

The negative binomial model uses a log link, not a logit link, so if you want to back-transform the coefficient to get proportional or "fold" changes per unit of `ind2`:

```r
exp(coef(m_sc)["ind.2"]/sc)
```

this gives 1.0373, a 4% change in the response per unit change in `ind.2` (you can confirm that it's the same as exponentiating the unscaled coefficient).

**Note** that 2/3 of the answers in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14512787/1640528), including the currently accepted answer, are wrong: you should be dividing the scaled coefficient by the scaling factor, not multiplying ...